# OpenJDK 1.8.0_242, MaxRAMFraction setting not reflecting

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jvm, containers

I am running a Springboot application in the alpine-OpenJDK image and facing OutOfMemory issues. Max heap is being capped at 256MB. I tried updating the MaxRAMFraction setting to 1 but did not see it getting reflected in the Java_process. I have an option to increase the container memory limit to 3000m but would prefer to use Cgroup memory with MaxRamfraction=1. Any thoughts?

```
Java-Version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.15.0) (Alpine 8.242.08-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

bash-5.0$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -Ei "maxheapsize|MaxRAMFraction"
    uintx DefaultMaxRAMFraction                     = 4                                   {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 262144000                           {product}
    uintx MaxRAMFraction                            = 4                                   {product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.15.0) (Alpine 8.242.08-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

Container Resource limits
 ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: 8080tcp02
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 350m
            memory: 1000Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 1000Mi
        securityContext:
          capabilities: {}
```

[Container JAVA_OPTS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3mkW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Max heap is being capped at 256MB.

You mean via `-m` in docker? If such, this is *not* the java heap you are specifying, but the total memory.

> I tried updating the MaxRAMFraction setting to 1

`MaxRAMFraction` is deprecated and un-used, forget about it.

> UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap

is deprecated and will be removed. Use `UseContainerSupport` that was ported to java-8 also.

> MaxRAM=2g

Do you know what this actually does? It sets the value for the "physical" RAM that the JVM is supposed to think you have.

I assume that you did not set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` on purpose here? Since you do not know how much memory the container will have? If such, we are in the same shoes. We *do* know that the min we are going to get is `1g`, but I have no idea of the max, as such I prefer not to set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` explicitly.

Instead, we do:

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=70
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70
-XX:+UseContainerSupport
-XX:InitialHeapSize=0
```

And that's it. What this does?

`InitialRAMPercentage` is used to calculate the initial heap size, BUT only when `InitialHeapSize/Xms` are missing. `MaxRAMPercentage` is used to calculate the *maximum heap*. Do not forget that a java process needs more than *just* `heap`, it needs native structures also; that is why that `70` (%).

Comment: The memory is capped to 256MB because by default JVM uses MaxRAMFraction=4. My container has 1024MB of memory and JVM caps at 256(please refer attached screenshot in question), and I was trying to override it by passing MaxRAMFraction 1. I did not realize it was deprecated and unused. I will try to UseContainerSupport and post back the feedback.Thanks