# How much headroom to leave between Java Xmx and Docker container RAM size?

Tags: java, docker, containers, java-heap

I'm 100% aware of the pitfalls of the JVM and advances/strides that have been done in the JVM world for it to understand the ergonomics/resources of a container. Also, yes I know that Java by default tries to allocate 1/4 the RAM available in the environment it's running...

So I had some thoughts and questions. I have made a 50/50 rule. If my application needs 1GB of Xmx, then I create 2GB container which gives another 1GB of RAM for the JVM overhead and any container/swap stuff (though not sure how swap really works within a container).

So I was thinking if my application needs 6GB of Xmx do I really need to create 12GB container or can I get away with 7GB or 8GB container? How much headroom do we need to give inside the container when it comes to RAM?

Comment: What frameworks/libs are you using? Are they using direct buffers. Is there anything using JNI like J2V8? What JVM version are you using? I use https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-memory-calculator to calculate the needed memory and than add things like netty.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it. The latest jdk8. Not doing anything super fancy. Kafka consumer, a bit caching in maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your container is dedicated to the JVM, then you don't need to use a percentage.

You need to know how much java heap you need -- in this case 6GB -- and how much everything else needs, which it looks like you've already proven is less than 2GB.

Then just add them up.  An 8GB container should be fine in this case.  Note that stack and heap memory are separate, though, so if you will need a large number of threads running simultaneously, don't forget to add 1MB of stack space for each one (or whatever you set with -Xss)

ALSO, I really recommend setting the minimum and maximum Java heap size to the SAME value -- 6GB in this case.   Then you're guaranteed that there will no surprises when Java tries to grow the heap.

Comment: The 2GB is an over simplified assumption! But I figured it should be more than enough for anything outside the heap, like JVM stack etc... Not doing anything fancy.

Comment: Of course, but it's an assumption you have experience with, right?  So now it's proven at least for some use cases.  The point is that the requirements for memory outside the heap aren't going to grow just because you need to grow the heap.  They'll grow if you need a whole lot more threads, or if you need a lot of direct buffers, etc.  Not in any way that is proportional to heap size

Comment: Correct. I think only when you start getting into memory mapped files etc... where you need at least double for caching etc... I was just more curious from container side as it can be smaller because there is no other processes running inside. At least from Docker perspective.

Comment: `how much everything else needs` is the most complicated part, depending on the application it might mean your GC performance, as unusual as it might sound. `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to the same value is a good advice, but if you don't it's not a big deal overall, this will trigger a page fault and expand of memory, OS-es that do not end in `DOWS` are rather good at that. Another advice you might give is to always pre-touch the memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* complicated question. The *heap* is only a portion of Java process; which has a lot of native resources also, not tracked with `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35248389/1059372) is a very nice summary about what these might be.

Then, there is the garbage collector algorithm that you use: the more freedom (extra-space) it has - the better. This has to do with so-called *GC barriers*. In very simple words, when GC is executed - all the heap manipulations will be "intercepted" and tracked separately. If the allocation rate is high, the space needed to track these changes (while an active GC happens) tends to grow. The more space you have - the better the GC will perform.

Then, it matters what java version you are using (because `-Xmx` and `-Xms` might mean different things under different java versions with respect to containers), for example [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198036/openjdk-1-8-0-242-maxramfraction-setting-not-reflecting/60200211#60200211).

So there is no easy answer here. If you *can* afford `12GB` of memory - do so. Memory is a lot cheaper (usually) than debugging any of the problems above.

Comment: But I was wondering if there's some specific guide to follow for container apps. I have it case by case, but I mostly apply 1:2 ratio for JVM to container. So if -Xmx1024 then I allocate 2048 to the container.

Comment: @user432024 I, personally, do not know of such a guide. We use heap + 30%, so far we have been good (3 years with 128 pods per cluster on average).